# How to assure all threads are stopped with shutdownNow()?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, rollback

I'm using Java's `ExecutorService` to run some tasks concurrently. I'm faced with this situation where I have multiple threads updating my DB, and if any of them throw an exception, I want to stop all of the running threads execution and rollback the DB.

I can do this with shutdownNow(). But there's a caveat in the docs:

> This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. 
>   Use awaitTermination to do that.

The plain ol `shutdown()` method has this same caveat, though. And I've read that the preferred way to use `shutdown()` is to wait for termination and call `shutdownNow()` if termination times out, such as:

```
executorService.shutdown();
try {
    executorService.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

So what do I do if `shutdownNow()` doesn't terminate everything right away? What would be the best way to make sure all the threads have stopped execution before rolling back the DB?

Comment: If you can ensure your threads respond to `Thread.interrupt()` then shutdownNow should stop all.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, but they won't all be stopped until some time _after_ the `shutdownNow()` call returns.

Comment: did you refer documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html ?

Answer (score 0):

> what do I do if shutdownNow() doesn't terminate everything right away?

File a bug report.  Then fix your code so that the `awaitTermination()` call never times out in the first place.  Either that, or else figure out a way to move whatever it is that those tasks are doing into a separate process that you can safely kill.